# Convert csv column of strings to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I saw numerous other posts proposing different solutions to this problem, but I cannot figure out how to adapt their solution approaches for my case, since I find it hard to understand how a method would extract the year, month, day etc. from my date format.

My dates are in the following format, including the timestamp behind the underscore:

```
20200929_180825
```

So it's `year(4)month(2)day(2)_hour(2)minute(2)seconds(2)`.

However, I need them to be in this format:

```
2018-12-04 14:37:29.261
```

I tried to write a script using **pd.to_datetime()** but failed to do so. I'm sure there must be a simple solution, but I just cannot wrap my head around how to do so. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['your_column'], format='%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your attempt at converting the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
dict = {'date': ['20200929_180825']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
print(df)
```

Comment: @chingg: Please consider voting up and accepting this answer if it helped !

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime,

```
from datetime import datetime

#Use strptime to make a datetime object from a String
date_obj = datetime.strptime("20200929_180825", "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

#Casting to string - Default str format from datetime is %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
date_str = str(date_obj)

print(date_str)
```